# Javascript. Reduce an array by adding only odd numbers. Javascript returns NaN when I use %2 on a number with if

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, nan, lf

I am trying to sum all odd numbers of an array.
The following method does not work and returns NaN. Could someone explain me why?
I found a workaround so I do not need an alternative code. It would be great if you could explain me why (a supposed number)%2 is NaN. Thanks a lot.
(I have just started learning Javascript. So sorry if this is ... )

```
let arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

let result = arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  if (currentValue%2 >0){
    return accumulator + currentValue}})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: If the `if` test is `false` the function will return `undefined`.

Comment: The callback of `.reduce()` _always_ has to return the value for `accumulator` of the next round: _"Your reducer function's returned value is assigned to the accumulator, whose value is remembered across each iteration throughout the array, and ultimately becomes the final, single resulting value."_

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the accumulator if the it's an odd number, so the last result is `undefined + 7` which is `NaN`.

Always return the current accumulator for even numbers, or the accumulator + the number if it's an odd number.

```js
const arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

const result = arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) =>
  currentValue % 2 > 0 ? accumulator + currentValue : accumulator
)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add an `else` clause inside the `reduce` method.

Because for even numbers you don't return anything which means the function returns `undefined` and now when the code encounters an odd number it does `undefined + something` which is `NaN`.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

let result = arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  if (currentValue % 2 > 0) {
    return accumulator + currentValue;
  } else {
    return accumulator
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You return [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) for all even values (this is [standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#description) for all functions without a [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)) and `undefined` can not be used to add a number.

For preventing this, you need to return the accumulator.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    result = arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
        if (currentValue % 2 > 0) {
            return accumulator + currentValue;
        } // or use else here
        return accumulator;
    });

console.log(result);
```